# What's the best way to say: "Brands who trust our work"

Tags: word-choice, phrases, expressions, expression-choice

What's the best way to say: "Brands who trust our work"  or "Brands that trust in our work"?

Comment: Second version is not idiomatically correct

Comment: The first, at least, is grammatical. But what exactly do you need to know?

Comment: @WS2 I have some banners of companies on a webpage and wanted to write a title for them, something like: "they work with us", "they trust us"

Comment: I'm not sure either is correct. How do brands distrust others' work?

Comment: I'm with Elliot.  I'd go for a more human connection...or at the very least, say "companies that trust our work".

Comment: ... Yes. A metonymy too far.

Comment: Now that it is clear what the OP is asking, I tend to the view that  there is nothing at all wrong with saying 'Brands that trust in our work'. It is the kind of thing you see all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you'd want to use the word **brands** here.  A brand is a trade name, an idea, etc.  Not an entity that trusts, feels, or otherwise has emotions.  It engenders these ideas in people, but doesn't have them for itself.

You mean **companies**.  And, you would say:  **Companies that trust our work.**

Or even, simply:

**Some of our clients:**

Answer (score 2):

-Trusted Affiliates-

(all of their logos here)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem was the who, would it sound better with that?

Instead of "Brands who trust our work" maybe use "Brands that trust our work"

The second approach sounds more like "In God we trust", giving a stronger sense, to emphasize.

- Brands that trust our work
- Brands that trust in our work

The original phrase was in spanish: Marcas que confían en nuestro trabajo